# Am in the UK and need to sell my late fathers shares, have no idea.where can i get some advice please

Tags: stocks, united-kingdom, shares, selling, inheritance

I have shares in Tesco and BP that are my late father's, as his executor I would like some advice as to best time to sell and how to go about it.

Can I do this on my own or do I need to pay a broker?

I have no idea where to look for the share price.

Comment: Welcome to Money.SE. I edited your post to include some more helpful tags (so it will be more likely to get noticed by people who can help) and cleaned up the formatting a bit. Hope this is OK.

Comment: Are the shares held in paper form or did your late father have an account with an online service? Share prices are in most papers or you can look them up online

Comment: Tesco live share price:  https://www.google.co.uk/finance?q=LON%3ATSCO&ei=7BtxVqD1DcO8U7rErsgI   You can get live prices for most stocks using that site.  Prices quoted are mid prices, you get slightly less if you sell.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I do this on my own or do I need to pay a broker?

If the shares are still in your fathers name, it would be ideal if you get these transferred to your name by showing the relevant paperwork to depository. If the shares are held in paper format, have these converted to electronic format before you can sell.

> I have no idea where to look for the share price.

Share prices are available on quite a few website and local newspapers.

> best time to sell and how to go about it.

There is no generic best or worst time. It depends on your goals. As indicated you would need to have them converted to your name and sell it via a broker. Your bank should be able to help you and offer these services.

Answer (score 3):

In the case of **Tesco**, the shares may be held by their **Corporate Sponsored Nominee** (CSN) which is **Equniti's ShareView** service. All shares held through a CSN appear on the official shareholder's register as owned by the CSN and they keep track of the real owners (see Equiniti's [Coporate Sponsored Nominee](http://www.shareview.co.uk/4/Info/Portfolio/default/en/home/products/Pages/Corporate-Sponsored-Nominee.aspx) page).

If your father's shares *are* in the Equiniti/ShareView CSN, then their [Manage an Estate page](http://www.shareview.co.uk/4/Info/Portfolio/default/en/home/shareholders/Pages/ManageEstate.aspx) may be of use. **Note**: If this is the case, registering your father's death with Equiniti using a **Grant of Representation** (Probate) will be  considerably cheaper than using their **Small Estate Service**.

(*Disclaimer: I have no connection with Equniti other than having had to deal with them a few years ago in connection with my parents' estates*).

---

In the case of **BP**, according to [this PDF document](https://www.bp.com/content/dam/bp/pdf/investors/bp-shareholder-administration-faqs-ordinary-and-preference-shareholders.pdf) (linked from BP's [Manage your Shares](https://www.bp.com/en/global/corporate/investors/information-for-shareholders/managing-your-shares.html) page) it appears Capita Asset Services provide the equivalent service – contact details for them are at the top of the PDF. The document also notes that *Equiniti* provided the service prior to October 2012.

Comment: Other activity on this question brought it to the front page of _Personal Finance & Money_, and I failed to realise when I added my answer that the question was asked just over two years ago, and – presumably – the matter has now been sorted. The last thing I would have wanted was to bring up memories of a bereavement. Hopefully, as the original poster's account appears to have been closed, they won't have got a notification of my answer, but in any case I apologise – I should have checked the date before responding.

Answer (score -1):

Usually in the case of an executor and death the companies that issue the shares will handle the sale for you; you can have them transferred into your name and take ownership if you wish but if you're just looking to sell them it can be easier to handle it through the issuing company.

The best time to sell really depends on how you think the shares will preform, however it's worth checking with the issuing company regarding sale after a death as some will honour the share price at the time and date of death even if higher than the current price.

Comment: Do you have some references for this? Generally it's brokers that handle share sales, and it's rather unlikely to get a free option to sell at a higher price.